# Possibly want Countifs but I'm not sure

Tags: excel

I'm building some sample data to go through my libraries. I know there are programs that will do this for me, but I'm just trying to figure out for myself.

I have 6 columns. The first is the Name of the Movie, the second the date, 3-5 would be the hard disk it's on, 6 would be if it's in my library already.

[image]

Right now I'm trying to compare my library to the other disks, but the problem is when i see a title that could have multiple dates. I.e.

[image]

So if I do a simple `=COUNTIF('PLEX Library'!A:A,A3)` it would show in the library, which should match the name on the other sheets.

Plex Library

[image]

However, as you can see the Date is in column I but I could have multiple Movies that have 1993 in the year. So doing `=COUNTIFS('PLEX Library'!A:A,A3,'PLEX Library'!I:AI,AI3)` wouldn't work.

So I feel like I need to do a VLook up for this in a CountIFS statement but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNTIFS` is good formula for what you need, because it counts if only all criteria are met. Your formula then would be:

```
=COUNTIFS('PLEX Library'!A:A,A3,'PLEX Library'!I:I,B3)
```

It will check if both name and date is same at the same time.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Now it makes since. I thought it was just going to look for the first 1993 it found.  Thank you so much